# Test code runs faster than database query

Tags: phpunit

I'm writing my tests using my local database, I know it's not really recommended to use an actual database, but not using it, is not really an option for me. Currently I'm facing a problem where my test executes faster than data is put into the database.

```
        $container = self::$container;
        $service = $container->get(CartService::class);

        $service->addItem($user, $boxitem, $parameters);
        $service->addItem($user, $boxitem, $parameters);
        $service->addItem($user, $boxitem, $parameters);
        $service->addItem($user, $boxitem, $parameters);

        $cart=$service->getCart($user);

        $service = $container->get(CartInfoService::class);

        $test = $service->getFullCartData($cart, $user);
```

Method `addItem` adds an item to my database. Method `getFullCartData`, gets data of those `items` from database. If I do it like this I get this error  `Error: Call to a member function matching() on null` it means that I'm trying to get `items` that are not there yet. If I put `addItem` methods into separate test that runs before this one, everything works fine, but I really don't like this solution

Current solution:

```
public function testTest()
    {
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(AdminUser::class)->findOneBy(array('id'=>4));
        $boxitem = $this->entityManager->getRepository(BoxItem::class)->findOneBy(array('id'=>149));

        $parameters=[
            'integrity'=> 100,
            'quantity'=> 1,
            'price'=> 500
        ];

        $container = self::$container;
        $service = $container->get(CartService::class);

        $service->addItem($user, $boxitem, $parameters);
        $service->addItem($user, $boxitem, $parameters);
        $service->addItem($user, $boxitem, $parameters);
        $service->addItem($user, $boxitem, $parameters);

    }

public function testGetFullCartData()
    {
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(AdminUser::class)->findOneBy(array('id'=>4));

        $container = self::$container;
        $service = $container->get(CartService::class);
        
        $cart=$service->getCart($user);

        $service = $container->get(CartInfoService::class);

        $test = $service->getFullCartData($cart, $user);

        var_dump($test);
    }
```

Is there a way to make the test wait for query to execute or maybe set up adding items some other way, before I try to get it?

Comment: What are you trying to test here, $service->getFullCartData, $service->addItem, or all the code calling these?

Comment: Since I can't use constructors in tests, I use `kernel` ,`doctrine` and `container` to get methods from other classes. I'm trying to test my project services, by giving it a random `item` and expecting a certain result. I understand why you might be confused by the code, it's not a complete test, I only need help to solve the delay of my database.

Comment: just a guess, so not saying this works: `unset($service);`  before you re-use the variable.

Comment: well, try it out if it makes a difference. splitting into two methods effectively unsets it and this may trigger flushing model changes to the database layer.

Comment: @hakre It did not help. I even tried putting `addItem` into to my `setUp()`, but it still can't keep up.

Comment: I think the problem might not be the database since after I use `addItem` my back-end checks if there's `items` added and if there is `cart` is created. It's even more complex than that, I think it uses 10 functions or something like that just to create `cart`. So maybe database is not the problem, but the complexity of the whole `cart` creation is.

Comment: Makes sense. As putting into the database is only half of the job, the other half is fetching from it. If you have the two test-methods scenario, can you see if the self::$container is reset between the tests? If not, maybe it is the culprit.

Comment: @hakre how can I check if container is being reset? I'm using `tearDown()` after each test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234434/discussion-between-hakre-and-belenka3000).